# Can I host the AASA file on heroku without the possibility of naked domains?

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

Since its not possible to have naked domains with heroku (in combination with godaddy), I can only forward my example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). Now when I check the validity of the AASA in

`branch.io/resources/aasa-validator`

and type [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), its all good. However, when I type example.com, I get validation error with 'A request to this domain failed'.

I wonder now why this happens since I forwarded it and also, will this cause issues and if so what to change based on the fact that the aasa file can only be reached with www, not with a naked domain?

Thanks!!

Comment: go with this link to know more about Heroku Architecture : https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/heroku-architecture  or https://copyprogramming.com/t/www-and-naked-domain-to-point-my-heroku-appI hope this helps you identify the queries you have.